# C++ when is it appropriate to use function templates to generate template functions rather than explicity wiritng the function?

Tags: c++, function-templates

Im doing some exam prep and I came across a short anwswer description question

"We want to perform some functionality independently on types X, Y and Z. When is it most appropriate to use function templates to generate 3 template functions rather than explicitly writing 3 functions?"

Im not entirely sure what this quesiton is asking for and cant seem to find anything about it on google

Comment: Note that function templates does not generate _template functions_. They generate _functions_, which are instances of that function template.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct X{ /**/ };
struct Y{ /**/ };
struct Z{ /**/ };
```

Do you prefer

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T& t)
{
     if (bar(t)) { foobar(t); }
}
```

over

```
void foo(X& t)
{
     if (bar(t)) { foobar(t); }
}
void foo(Y& t)
{
     if (bar(t)) { foobar(t); }
}
void foo(Z& t)
{
     if (bar(t)) { foobar(t); }
}
```

Do you prefer

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T& t);

template <>
void foo<X>(X& t)
{
     if (barX(t)) { foobarX(t); }
}
template <>
void foo<Y>(Y& t)
{
     foobarY(t);
}
template <>
void foo<Z>(Z& t)
{
     if (barZ(t)) { foobarZ(t); }
}
```

over

```
void foo(X& t)
{
     if (barX(t)) { foobarX(t); }
}

void foo(Y& t)
{
     foobarY(t);
}

void foo(Z& t)
{
     if (barZ(t)) { foobarZ(t); }
}
```